# Round down to nearest quarter hour using AWK w/ file input

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a comma delimited file where one field contains a datetime in the following format:

01/15/2014 13:53

I need to round the time portion of this field down to the nearest quarter hour. I can get awk to perform the rounding with just the date/time as the input, but I'm having trouble getting awk to read the file & perform the rounding. Here's the awk command used for rounding the date/time as direct input:

```
echo "04/17/2014 12:59" | awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/15)*15}'
```

How would I perform this same rounding using an entire file as input with the date/time being the 3rd field in a comma delimited file?

Comment: In essentially the same way. You can still operate on just the part after the `:` with your `split` the main differences are that you want to split the `$3` field and that you want to assign your result `a[1],int(...)` back to `$3` and then `print`.

Comment: @EtanReisner How would you assign the result back to $3. Something like - $3=printf .... or would you need to surround it in ()?

Comment: Basically like I said: `$3=a[1],int(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    function round_time(t,   a) {
        split(t,a,/:/)
        return sprintf("%s:%02d", a[1], int(a[2] / 15)*15)
    }
    {$3 = round_time($3); print}
' << END
a,b,01/15/2014 13:53,d
e,f,01/15/2014 14:13,h
END
```

```
a,b,01/15/2014 13:45,d
e,f,01/15/2014 14:00,h
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Could you explain the function declaration? I understand 't' is the input but what's the 'a' for and the spacing before it?

Comment: If you don't name variables in the function's argument list, then they will be global variables. It's an awk convention to put all variables you want to be local to the function in the argument list, and the space is denote the difference between arguments that are to be passed in versus local vars. Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl` would be compact and straightforward:

```
$ echo "04/17/2014 12:59" | perl -pe 's|(?<=:)\d\d\b|int($&/15)*15|ge'
04/17/2014 12:45
```

Explanation:

- The `-pe` flag of `perl` is to run the expression for each line, possibly modifying it, and then print the resulting line, behaving similar to `sed` or `awk`
- The `(?<=:)\d\d\b` expression matches two digits following a `:` without including the `:` in the matched pattern (a zero-width positive look-behind). The `\b` marks a word boundary, so this won't match ":123"
- The `$&` in the replacement is the matched pattern, in this example that's 59
- The `e` flag in the `s///e` command is to evaluate the replacement as a perl script, allowing to perform the `int(... / 15) * 15` arithmetic on the matched pattern
- Instead of `/` in the `s///` command we use `|` as the separator so that we can use `/` in the replacement pattern